# Can i log http traffic from an app service in Azure?

Tags: azure

I have an app service in Azure that is part of a 3 way handshake , but i receive the error:

Duplicate TCP SYN from ISP_1:<ip1/port1> to :<ip2/port2> with different initial sequence number ?

I assume that it indicates that the source side ISP_1 is not receiving a SYN/ACK packet from the destination  during the 3-way handshake in the expected time frame so it issues another SYN packet
and i get the error "Unable to connect to the remote server".

The app service is hosted on Azure.
If I turn on application insights , how can i capture both in bound and outbound traffic with dns names  and also if there is anything that the firewall has denied in Azure ?

Answer (score -1):

Enable App Insights, and use the ILogger to log whatever you want into Azure Logs, they can be found in the traces table once you enable the logging.

By default there is no firewall in your App Service unless you enabled it.

Comment: I have enabled App service logs: Now its quite confusing as the logs dont really provide a well structured order of events.

So if i enable Application Insights doesnt it automatically log http requests , where can i view these logs ?
why do i need to use Ilogger in my .net app and redeploy.
Im trying to get a clearer understanding of all this .

Comment: There is a 3 way handshake and what seems to be happening is that the return request is not coming back or timing out. Could be blocked but network guys seem to think nothing is blocking the traffic. The app service doesnt receive a response in the timeframe and then sends another but there is an error Duplicate TCP SYN from ISP_<ip_address> to <INTERNAL>:<ip_address/port> with different initial sequence number . So i am trying to get a log that shows the requests being sent and received, Does that exist in Azure App Service logging ? if so how can i configure it ?

Comment: @Kylie sure you can log anything you want including requests and responses using ILogger, not really sure what the actual question is? if you are looking at network traces on a pure L3 level thats different but I dont think thats your question.

Comment: I will try to explain it clearly hopefully its more understandable. I have an app service the sends requests , to a third party app. Now during a 3 way handshake to establish a tcp connection before sending data the network teams seems to think there is  request send from my app service that causes an error, as above.  All i need is some sort of log that can log the request being sent from the app . So for example POST request to Google.com etc. I thought i will be able to see all the request being snt and received ?  Does ILogger need to be added to the app service and then deployed ?

Comment: so just use ILogger and log the POST request and the response and you can see exactly what happens, if you are using Azure Functions then ILogger is available by default

Comment: Im using a .net app in Azure. Is Ilogger available , if so isthere a tutorial that explains how todo this process?

Comment: @Kylie log.logInformational(whatever you want to log); then go to app insights and search the traces table for your logs, if you include a simple keyword in your log message like "jongel" or something then it makes it easy to search